# Find Installed OS on Hard Drive

Tags: operating-system, bootloader

About three years ago I had a dual boot laptop. One day, it wouldn't boot at all, not either OS. I found a shareware program that looked for the OS's installed on the hard drive and let you run the chosen OS. I think it let you fix the MBR as well. The program worked at the DOS level, that is, it booted itself without needing the existing, yet unreachable, OS's on the hard drive. I can't remember the name of it, and I can't find it.

Anyone? Bueller?

Comment: Found it: https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/